# How to use (local) variable/parameter in test step

Tags: soapui

I have a teststep that contains this XML:

```
<mes:ItemIds>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="1"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="2"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="3"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="4"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="5"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA==" InstanceIndex="6"/>
...
```

I execute this manually in the free version of SOAPUI.

When I need to test with a different RecurringMasterId, a global replace is possible, but I'd rather do something like

```
somevariable="AQMkADkyZTQxNjUzLTcwZTQtNGRlNS04M2VmLWMxYmIBNWJiADUwZTYARgAAA4Kt4mOTlXZJrZx0v5cQm8IHAISmF1hx/2pAhQBTVUBmYgoAAAMhAAAAhKYXWHH/akCFAFNVQGZiCgACKdAKmwAAAA=="
<mes:ItemIds>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="1"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="2"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="3"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="4"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="5"/>
  <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=somevariable InstanceIndex="6"/>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add custom property to the test case, then add Groovy Script step before request. In the script set your property (`somevariable`) like described here http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html and access to property in request this way `<typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId=${#TestCase#somevariable}  InstanceIndex="1"/>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Quite a lot of work, not surprising I could not find it in the help ;-) One question though: my variable is specific to *one* teststep, but it looks as if the test case is the nearest level (up) that I can define the property, right? That's a bit awkward.

Comment: Writing such scripts for handling properties will take not so much time :) I am not sure you can define custom property for test step (at least in free version, probably possible for SoapUIPro version).

Comment: Thanks, this was it. It can be done without Groovy: I defined a custom property propMasterID (at the testcase level), and now my XML has RecurringMasterId="${#TestCase#propMasterID}"